# JTable and Database in Swing

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable

I need to load database content into a `JTable`. Many times I search for help. Please anybody can refer a tutorial please, otherwise anybody can help me to do so.

Comment: If you only looking for a tutorial, please write that in the headline. Or if not, give us some idea of what you have done already or show us some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you need to implement a [`TableModel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) that is backed by the database. [Here's](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/swinghks_hack24/index.html) a simple example of how that could be done.